# How can I approximate the periodicity of a pandas time Series

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to approximate the periodicity of a time series in pandas? For R, the `xts` objects have a method called `periodicity` that serves exactly this purpose. Is there an implemented method to do so?

For instance, can we infer the frequency from time series that do not specify frequency?

```
import pandas.io.data as web
aapl = web.get_data_yahoo("AAPL")

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2010-01-04 00:00:00, ..., 2013-12-19 00:00:00]
Length: 999, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

The frequency of this series can reasonably be approximated to be daily.

**Update:**

I think it might be helpful to show the source code of R's implementation of the periodicity method.

```
function (x, ...) 
{
    if (timeBased(x) || !is.xts(x)) 
        x <- try.xts(x, error = "'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible")
    p <- median(diff(.index(x)))
    if (is.na(p)) 
        stop("can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation")
    units <- "days"
    scale <- "yearly"
    label <- "year"
    if (p < 60) {
        units <- "secs"
        scale <- "seconds"
        label <- "second"
    }
    else if (p < 3600) {
        units <- "mins"
        scale <- "minute"
        label <- "minute"
        p <- p/60L
    }
    else if (p < 86400) {
        units <- "hours"
        scale <- "hourly"
        label <- "hour"
    }
    else if (p == 86400) {
        scale <- "daily"
        label <- "day"
    }
    else if (p <= 604800) {
        scale <- "weekly"
        label <- "week"
    }
    else if (p <= 2678400) {
        scale <- "monthly"
        label <- "month"
    }
    else if (p <= 7948800) {
        scale <- "quarterly"
        label <- "quarter"
    }
    structure(list(difftime = structure(p, units = units, class = "difftime"), 
        frequency = p, start = start(x), end = end(x), units = units, 
        scale = scale, label = label), class = "periodicity")
}
```

I think this line is the key, which I don't quite understand
`p <- median(diff(.index(x)))`

Comment: Would a fourier transform possibly help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This time series skips weekends (and holidays), so it really doesn't have a daily frequency to begin with. You could use `asfreq` to upsample it to a time series with daily frequency, however:

```
aapl = aapl.asfreq('D', method='ffill')
```

Doing so propagates forward the last observed value to dates with missing values.

Note that Pandas also has a business day frequency, so it is also possible to upsample to business days by using:

```
aapl = aapl.asfreq('B', method='ffill')
```

---

If you wish to automate the process of inferring the median frequency in days, then you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.io.data as web
aapl = web.get_data_yahoo("AAPL")
f  = np.median(np.diff(aapl.index.values))
days = f.astype('timedelta64[D]').item().days
aapl = aapl.asfreq('{}D'.format(days), method='ffill')
print(aapl)
```

---

This code needs testing, but perhaps it comes close to the R code you posted:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.io.data as web

def infer_freq(ts):
    med  = np.median(np.diff(ts.index.values))
    seconds = int(med.astype('timedelta64[s]').item().total_seconds())
    if seconds < 60:
        freq = '{}s'.format(seconds)
    elif seconds < 3600:
        freq = '{}T'.format(seconds//60)
    elif seconds < 86400:
        freq = '{}H'.format(seconds//3600)
    elif seconds < 604800:
        freq = '{}D'.format(seconds//86400)
    elif seconds < 2678400:
        freq = '{}W'.format(seconds//604800)
    elif seconds < 7948800:
        freq = '{}M'.format(seconds//2678400)
    else:
        freq = '{}Q'.format(seconds//7948800)
    return ts.asfreq(freq, method='ffill')

aapl = web.get_data_yahoo("AAPL")
print(infer_freq(aapl))
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about frequency, the only meaningful measure I can come up with is mean timedelta, for example in days:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> idx = aapl.index.values
>>> (np.roll(idx, -1) - idx)[:-1].mean()/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
1.4478957915831596
```

or in hours:

```
>>> (np.roll(idx, -1) - idx)[:-1].mean()/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
34.749498997995836
```

The same with a more *pandorable* expression, kudos to @DSM:

```
>>> aapl.index.to_series().diff().mean() / (60*60*10**9)
34.749498997995993
```

Sure median will be 24 hours, as most of days exist in list:

```
>>> aapl.index.to_series().diff().median() / (60*60*10**9)
24.0
```

Comment: I think it's more pandorable to write `aapl.index.to_series().diff().mean()` or `.median()`.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, this `to_series` is what I missed to be able to use `.diff()`.